# ggplot2: geom_histogram 'Y' axis aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to cheat a bit on the fact that ggplot2 does not support multiple axes (I know it's not ideally correct to use 2 axes).
I have a `geom_point` and would like to add a `geom_histogram` on top of it. The cheat here would be to somehow manipulate the 'Y' axis scaling to match the one from `geom_point`.

`geom_histogram` syntax goes something like this:

```
geom_histogram(data=df, aes(x=x1, y=..count..))
```

The interesting part for me is the 'y' axis in the aesthetics, this `..count..` (or `..density..`, `..ncount..`, etc) can be manipulated for example by doing this:

```
geom_histogram(data=df, aes(x=x1, y=..count..+100))
```

and this would add 100 to whatever was your count of variable x1 in each bin:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(200))

ggplot(df)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=x1, y=..count..+100))
```

Now, when I try to do the same but replacing the '100' with a variable, I get an error:

```
var <- 100

ggplot(df)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=x1, y=..count..+var))

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'var' not found
```

I suppose this error comes because I am inside `aes()` so my question would be: why is this happening and how can I use a variable to manipulate this 'y' axis?